# SAPUI5 - Y Axis title sap.viz.ui5.Line

Tags: graph, sapui5

I'm trying to remove the title from the Y axis on a UI5 viz graph (sap.viz.ui5.Line)
[image]

I tried looking at the API on the yAxis agrregation on the sap.viz.ui5.Line control but I get nothing regarding this option.

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks1

Answer (score 2):

It is an old post but may be the reply could help other developers as I had the same requirement and I solved it by setting the title visibility of the valueAxis(y-axis) to false, for (x-axis) you can do the same using categoryAxis

//using Javascript

`oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
    valueAxis: {
        title: {`

```
        visible: false, //set the title visibility to false
        text: "Value Axis Value"
    }
}});
```

//using XML

```
vizProperties="{ valueAxis: { title: { visible: false, text: ' valueAxis text' } }}"
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's a completely wrong answer. oVizFrame is not the same as sap.viz.ui5.Line. sap.viz.ui5.Line was depricated a while back but still used in legacy systems.